# Привилегии не записываются в information_schema

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Создал нового пользователя:

```
CREATE USER 'kergudu'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

выдал ему права на БД:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON basename.* TO 'kergudu'@'%';
MariaDB> flush privileges;
```

После чего удаленно получается подключиться к базе, но при любом запросе получаю

```
Access denied for user 'kergudu'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

При этом:

```
MariaDB> show grants for 'kergudu'@'%';

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for kergudu@%                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'kergudu'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*LONGLONGPASSWORDHASH' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `basename`.* TO 'kergudu'@'%'                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Но!

```
MariaDB> select * from information_schema.user_privileges;
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE             | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE      | IS_GRANTABLE |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 'kergudu'@'%'       | def           | USAGE               | NO           |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: FLUSH PRIVILEGES?

Comment: Конечно. И поэтому дает подключиться к базе. Но непонятно, почему не дает выполнять запросы. Исправил в посте.